# Calling generic method with Mono Cecil

Tags: c#, .net, generics, mono, cil

I'd like to inject IL code into methods, which calls a Generic method (With return type and arguments).

```
public static T MyGenericMethod<T>(T genericArg, string nonGenericArg)
{
    //Do something with genericArg
    return genericArg;
}
```

I can call non generic methods, but I have no idea how to call a generic method.

My question is, how could I inject this generic method call into a method?

Example for Non-Generic method injection:

1, Open the assembly and get the non generic method info

```
        DefaultAssemblyResolver resolver = new DefaultAssemblyResolver();
        resolver.AddSearchDirectory(assemblyResolverPath);
        AssemblyDefinition myLibrary = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyPath, new ReaderParameters() { AssemblyResolver = resolver });

        MethodInfo writeLineMethod = typeof(Debug).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        MethodReference writeLine = myLibrary.MainModule.Import(writeLineMethod);
```

2, Inject the "WriteLine" method into the choosen method:

```
                ILProcessor ilProcessor = method.Body.GetILProcessor();

                Instruction callWriteLine = ilProcessor.Create(OpCodes.Call, writeLine);

                ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ins, "CALL");
                ilProcessor.InsertBefore(ins, callWriteLine);
```

This will result the following extra IL instructions in the choosen method:

```
IL_0001: ldstr        "CALL"
IL_0006: call         void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

But in case of a Generic method, I should receive this IL:

```
IL_0001: ldc.i4.s     10 // 0x0a
IL_0003: ldstr        "CALL"
IL_0008: call         !!0/*int32*/ ReturnTestModule.ReturnTest::MyGenericMethod<int32>(!!0/*int32*/, string)
```

I have to handle the generic arguments and the return value type definitely, but I do not know, how should I do it.

Comment: Can you please post a little example that shows how to inject non-generic methods? I might be able to help you out if I see how you are trying.

Comment: Non-Generic method example added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are basically on the right track. All you have to do is get a reference to the generic method, like you did it for the non-generic version. The difference is that for a generic method, this will give you the MethodInfo of the open generic method and you have to close it first, using the `MakeGeneric()` method and passing the types that you want the method to have as generic type arguments.

```
MethodInfo openGenericMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod("MyGenericMethod");
/// this will create a reference to MyGenericMethod<int>()
MethodInfo closedGenericMethod = openGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
```

And then proceed with getting the `MethodReference`, creating the `ILProcessor` and inserting the instruction.